# What is the difference between ばよかったです and べき?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between ばよかったです and べき?

> あのバスに乗ればよかったです。
>   I should have taken that bus.
>
> あのバスに乗るべきだった。
>   I should have taken that bus.
>
> このバスに乗れるはずじゃなかった。
>   I wasn’t supposed to get on this bus.
>
> 簡単なはずです。
>   It should be easy.

Comment: Why the last two sentences? Are you asking about the difference between はず and the other two as well?

Answer (score 3):

ばよかった - "should have" in the sense "I wish I had" or "it would have been better if I had"

べき - "should have" in the sense of "ought to". There is some expectation from the outside, some other people, or society as a whole that you should better do it.

はず - in contrast to べき, the expectation or assumption here comes from yourself, prior experience etc.

Answer (score 1):

ばよかった - means "I wish I had" , you're regret about something

for example:
"彼女と別れればよかった" = "I with i had broke up with my girlfriend"

べき -  means "you're supposed to do something " or "you're responsible for doing sth"

for example:
"今日中にすべき仕事"　= "The work have to be done today"

Hope this helps