# "Should have" in japanese

Tags: word-choice

How to verbalize "should have" in the given example below.

```
I should have ordered chicken (Because the fish I ordered is terrible)
```

There are 2 ways that I can think of and the is　鶏肉を注文したはず or 鶏肉を注文するべき

But to me, these 2 sentences doesn't sound very right because if I explicitly say 魚がまずいので鶏肉を注文**はず**, the はず part just doesn't fit the bill (does not sound right). The question is, is there a better word to use in such a situation?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73257/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30188/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Definitely answered the question. Cheers。Just to add, is it possible to use たら良かった rather then すれば良かった？ たら良かった sounds right to me too but I might be wrong

Comment: 注文すればよかった、注文したらよかった both sound fine. したらよかった sounds more colloquial.